# Proper way to type cast based on object instance

Tags: java, oop

I have a very basic question which is more of a design question. Listed below are the classes where **User** is an abstract class. Only **PremiumUser** and **AdminUser** can post messages whereas **GuestUser** can't post messages (hence there is no *postedMessages;* property in the **GuestUser** class).

[image]

PROBLEM:
I have a main class from where I call the *postMessage()*; method but before calling this method I get the **User** object using another method (whose return type is **User**). So, to call the *postMessage()* method, I will have to typecast the **User** object into either **AdminUser** or **PremiumUser** object. I see three ways to do that:

1. Use the property *userType* in **User** class to make if-else comparison and typecast based on that.
2. Use java reflection to get method list for the object and call the *postMessage* method.
3. Consider using an interface: I considered using an interface which will be implemented by **AdminUser** and **PremiumUser** class. Even in that case, I can't type cast the object of type **User** into the type *interface* and use it seamlessly to call *postMessage();*

I was wondering if my design is deficient in some way or it is a common problem and there is a smarter solution for this.

Comment: @RC. I have already considered implementing an interface by PremiumUser and AdminUser class. Even in that scenario, I can't type cast the object of type User into the interface and use it seamlessly . (I'll rather add this to the question itself)

Comment: Just pass the User object, and check for errors in the called method.  You can't declare a method that takes PremiumUser and AdminUser without including GuestUser anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an interface with the `postMessage` method in it:

```
interface HasPostMessage {
    boolean postMessage(String message);
}
```

Make `PremiumUser` and `AdminUser` implement it. Then:

```
if (user instanceOf HasPostMessage) {
    ((HasPostMessage) user).postMessage("The message");
}
```

Comment: Okay, so basically this way I will have to use only one "if" condition instead of two

Answer (score 1):

To safe cast you basically use something like:

```
PremiumUser.class.isAssignableFrom(object);
```

which also works for objects that inherit from PremiumUser (for example). There are multiple options to avoid this check but it is entirely a matter of design. Some examples:

- Declare the postMessage() method in User class and implement it differently for each type of user.
- Implement Groups, Roles and Rights and check if the particular User has the right to post messages.